# query with case when

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is a query to flag and allow only few ID's based on filtering over entry_date:

```
SELECT A.ID_NO,A.CATEGORY,
CASE WHEN 
(SELECT * FROM NEW_TEST B 
WHERE CATEGORY IN ('ODS','L')
) 
THEN 'ALLOW'
ELSE 'DENY'
END AS NEW_COL
FROM NEW_TEST A;
```

But this query is giving error , is there a way to use window functions or any other method

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement.  Sample data and desired results help.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you really want to know if there are three rows for ODS and L categories for each id and date.  If so:

```
SELECT A.ID_NO, A.ENTRY_DATE, A.CATEGORY,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY IN ('ODS', 'L') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_NO, ENTRY_DATE) < 3
             THEN 'ALLOW' ELSE 'DENY'
        END) as NEW_COL
FROM NEW_TEST A;
```

However, your code is checking each category independently, which would be:

```
SELECT A.ID_NO, A.ENTRY_DATE, A.CATEGORY,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'ODS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_NO, ENTRY_DATE) < 3 OR
                  SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_NO, ENTRY_DATE) < 3
             THEN 'ALLOW' ELSE 'DENY'
        END) as NEW_COL
FROM NEW_TEST A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a proper JOIN.  Here's your same logic w/o the correlated subquery:

```
SELECT A.ID_NO,A.ENTRY_DATE,A.CATEGORY,
 NVL(B.NEW_COL, 'DENY') AS NEW_COL
  FROM NEW_TEST A
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID_NO, ENTRY_DATE, 'ALLOW' AS NEW_COL 
             FROM NEW_TEST B 
             WHERE CATEGORY IN ('ODS','L')
             GROUP BY B.ID_NO,B.ENTRY_DATE,B.CATEGORY
             HAVING COUNT(1)<3) B
  ON B.ID_NO=A.ID_NO AND B.ENTRY_DATE=A.ENTRY_DATE ;
```

You don't need window functions for this.  Seems odd that you are grouping on 3 columns but joining on 2 but I'm assuming you know what this needs to do.

Comment: The solution above has different group by and join columns and produces the same result as your code.  I was just pointing this out b/c it is unusual - if it is right for you, your good.  Does it not work in the real case?

Comment: Because you are keeping ENTRY_DATE in the WHERE clause of the sub-select the data in the group by will be for the ENTRY_DATE of the row being evaluated.  So the answer I gave is correct for this case.  You also don't need ID_NO in the group by either for your code since this is static due to the WHERE clause.  The correlated subquery error you are getting from Redshift is due to exactly this - for every row in the outer part of the query it needs to run the inner select for the values of ID_NO and ENTRY_DATE.  It is this rerunning the sub-query for every row that Redshift doesn't do.

Comment: In the join based solution I provided you need to group by every column that will be used to join on.  This ensures that you are only evaluating groups that will match the row in question.  In the correlated subquery approach the WHERE clause filters the rows down to only matching and makes a determination.  In the join approach we need to make all the groups with the determination added and join these to the rows of the original table.

Comment: The row increase is due to CATEGORY being the the group by but no the join on.  It didn't may a difference in the test case you provided.  I assume you did this b/c you wanted any category that matched the criteria to effect all categories for the same ENTRY_DATE and ID_NO.  This seemed odd but I don't know your biz.  If you want this behavior wrap the inner select in another select only grouping on ENTRY_DATE and ID_NO.  You will need to do a MIN(NEW_COL) so that all the "ALLOW"s come through.  This way you will have 1:1 joining an no row replication.

Comment: When there is a 1:1 relationship between the 2 sides of join then you cannot get more rows than the largest of the 2 table.  If there is a 1:many relationship then you the rows on the left side of this join will be replicated in the act of joining.  So If you join a table with itself but the second version is grouped by col A.  And the join on condition is A=A there cannot be an increase of the rows on the left side - each row has a value of A and there is only one row with that value on the right side due to the group by.

Comment: However, if we join the table with itself grouped by A & B but only join on A then the left side rows will be duplicated for each value of B that has the same A as the left side.  In your case you want any single grouping of ENTRY_DATE, ID_NO, and CATEGORY with size < 3 to mark all rows with matching ENTRY_DATE and ID_NO (but all values of CATEGORY) as "ALLOW".  This means make groups base on all 3 columns but only join base on 2.  This leads to replicated rows (just like the example above).

Comment: To address this will need to have only 2 group by columns when we join.  So we can run an additional select that takes the groupings based on 3 columns and merges then down to groupings of 2 columns AND uses the value of any of the 3-group data being ALLOW as an indicator that the 2-group data is also ALLOW.   We need the 3 column groups to know if the <3 condition is met but the 2 column groups to join w/o replication.  Make sense?